# Debug Compiled NASM Files with GDB

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, nasm

I have files I've written in NASM. Specifically a TCP Bind shell that is not working and I'm looking to debug.

How can I go about doing this:

```
SECTION .text
       global _start
_start:
       ; stuff ...
       ; stuff ...
```

I'm running a x64 bit machine and I've writtn it in x86 ASM. Now, I compiled it with the following.

```
nasm -elf32 -o temp.o file.asm
ld -s -m elf_i386 -o bind temp.o
```

Then:

```
gdb bind
```

When I search for `disassemble X` there are no frames. How can I disassemble it and show the ESP and registers? Set breakpoints...

Comment: You left out a lowercase 'f' in your post. An uppercase 'F' selects debug info format. `-F dwarf` may help. A `nop` right after the `_start:` label may help. Oh, and no `-s` switch to ld!!!

Comment: Please add that as the answer and I'll "accept" it. The `-s` needed to be deleted. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, consider it an "answer"...

You left out a lowercase 'f' in your post. An uppercase 'F' selects debug info format. -F dwarf may help. A nop right after the _start: label may help. Oh, and no -s switch to ld!!!